# Why does \maketitle break my document?

Tags: titles, document-classes

I have a paper to submit in an hour, and have an issue with the `\maketitle` command. The template provided to me *does not work*, and the instructor has told me to figure it out on my  own.

Here is a simplified example:

```
\documentclass{bioinfo}
\copyrightyear{2014}
\pubyear{2014}

\begin{document}
\firstpage{1}

\title[QTL Analysis]{Evaluation of a QTL Dataset}
\author[Robert R. Gotwals]{Robert R. Gotwals\,\footnote{to whom correspondence should be addressed}}
\address{$^{1}$Department of XXXXXXX, Address XXXX etc.}

\history{Received on XXXXX; revised on XXXXX; accepted on XXXXX}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}

Here's the abstract. 

\section{Keywords:} first, second, third, fourth

\section{Contact:} \href{cowbell@ncssm.edu}{gotwals@ncssm.edu}
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore. 


\end{document}
```

The `.log` file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2013.12.9)  28 MAY 2014 20:50

entering extended mode

**document.tex



("C:\Users\chire001\Documents\Jeffrey Files\School\CompBio\Final Project\Docume

nt\document.tex"

LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>

Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ar

abic, armenian, assamese, basque, bengali, bokmal, bulgarian, catalan, coptic, 

croatian, czech, danish, dutch, esperanto, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, ga

lician, german, german-x-2012-05-30, greek, gujarati, hindi, hungarian, iceland

ic, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kannada, kurmanji, latin, latvian,

 lithuanian, malayalam, marathi, mongolian, mongolianlmc, monogreek, ngerman, n

german-x-2012-05-30, nynorsk, oriya, panjabi, pinyin, polish, portuguese, roman

ian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, swissgerm

an, tamil, telugu, turkish, turkmen, ukenglish, ukrainian, uppersorbian, usengl

ishmax, welsh, loaded.



("C:\Users\chire001\Documents\Jeffrey Files\School\CompBio\Final Project\Docume

nt\bioinfo.cls"

Document Class: bioinfo 2003/02/08 0.1

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\inputenc.sty"

Package: inputenc 2008/03/30 v1.1d Input encoding file

\inpenc@prehook=\toks14

\inpenc@posthook=\toks15

)

("C:\Users\chire001\Documents\Jeffrey Files\School\CompBio\Final Project\Docume

nt\crop.sty"

Package: crop 2001/11/16 v1.6 cropmarks (mf)

\CROP@width=\dimen102

\CROP@height=\dimen103

\CROP@index=\count79

 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty"

Package: graphics 2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)



("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty"

Package: trig 1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)

)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\graphics.cfg"

File: graphics.cfg 2007/01/18 v1.5 graphics configuration of teTeX/TeXLive

)

Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 91.



("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pdftex-def\pdftex.def"

File: pdftex.def 2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX



("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\infwarerr.sty"

Package: infwarerr 2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)

)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty"

Package: ltxcmds 2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)

)

\Gread@gobject=\count80

))

\CROP@offset=\count81

Package crop Info: Local config file crop.cfg used on input line 344.



("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\xelatex\xetexconfig\crop.cfg"))

Package crop Info: using pdf(la)tex graphics driver on input line 33.



("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty"

Package: graphicx 1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)



("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty"

Package: keyval 1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)

\KV@toks@=\toks16

)

\Gin@req@height=\dimen104

\Gin@req@width=\dimen105

)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsmath.sty"

Package: amsmath 2013/01/14 v2.14 AMS math features

\@mathmargin=\skip41



For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amstext.sty"

Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01



("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsgen.sty"

File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0

\@emptytoks=\toks17

\ex@=\dimen106

))

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsbsy.sty"

Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d

\pmbraise@=\dimen107

)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsopn.sty"

Package: amsopn 1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names

)

\inf@bad=\count82

LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 210.

\uproot@=\count83

\leftroot@=\count84

LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 306.

\classnum@=\count85

\DOTSCASE@=\count86

LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 378.

LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 381.

LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 466.

\Mathstrutbox@=\box26

\strutbox@=\box27

\big@size=\dimen108

LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 566.

LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 567.

\macc@depth=\count87

\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count88

\dotsspace@=\muskip10

\c@parentequation=\count89

\dspbrk@lvl=\count90

\tag@help=\toks18

\row@=\count91

\column@=\count92

\maxfields@=\count93

\andhelp@=\toks19

\eqnshift@=\dimen109

\alignsep@=\dimen110

\tagshift@=\dimen111

\tagwidth@=\dimen112

\totwidth@=\dimen113

\lineht@=\dimen114

\@envbody=\toks20

\multlinegap=\skip42

\multlinetaggap=\skip43

\mathdisplay@stack=\toks21

LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2665.

LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2666.

)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tools\array.sty"

Package: array 2008/09/09 v2.4c Tabular extension package (FMi)

\col@sep=\dimen115

\extrarowheight=\dimen116

\NC@list=\toks22

\extratabsurround=\skip44

\backup@length=\skip45

)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\color.sty"

Package: color 2005/11/14 v1.0j Standard LaTeX Color (DPC)



("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\color.cfg"

File: color.cfg 2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive

)

Package color Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 130.

)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\amssymb.sty"

Package: amssymb 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols



("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\amsfonts.sty"

Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support

\symAMSa=\mathgroup4

\symAMSb=\mathgroup5

LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'

(Font)                  U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 106.

))

(C:\Users\chire001\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\sttools\flushend.sty

Package: flushend 2014/04/24 v2.2 Balancing columns in twocolumn mode

\flushend@@lastskip@a=\skip46

\flushend@@lastskip@b=\skip47

\flushend@@lastskip@c=\skip48

\flushend@@penalty@a=\count94

\flushend@@lastkern@a=\dimen117

\var@@temp@spread=\dimen118

\var@@temp@a=\dimen119

\flushend@@page@rule=\dimen120

\flushend@@varbox@a=\box28

\flushend@@varbox@c=\box29

\flushend@@tempbox@a=\box30

\flushend@@tempbox@c=\box31

\@viper=\box32

\hold@viper=\box33

\atColsBreak=\toks23

\atColsEnd=\toks24



(C:\Users\chire001\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\etoolbox\etoolbox.sty

Package: etoolbox 2011/01/03 v2.1 e-TeX tools for LaTeX



("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\misc\etex.sty"

Package: etex 1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)

\et@xins=\count95

)

\etb@tempcnta=\count96

))

(C:\Users\chire001\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\sttools\stfloats.sty

Package: stfloats 2012/05/29 v1.1 Improve float mechanism and baselineskip sett

ings

\@dblbotnum=\count97

\c@dblbotnumber=\count98

)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amscls\amsthm.sty"

Package: amsthm 2004/08/06 v2.20

\thm@style=\toks25

\thm@bodyfont=\toks26

\thm@headfont=\toks27

\thm@notefont=\toks28

\thm@headpunct=\toks29

\thm@preskip=\skip49

\thm@postskip=\skip50

\thm@headsep=\skip51

\dth@everypar=\toks30

)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\ltxmisc\chngpage.sty"

Package: chngpage 2003/08/10 v1.2 change page layout

\c@cp@cnt=\count99

\c@cp@tempcnt=\count100

)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\psnfss\times.sty"

Package: times 2005/04/12 PSNFSS-v9.2a (SPQR) 

)

\c@section=\count101

\c@subsection=\count102

\c@subsubsection=\count103

\c@paragraph=\count104

\c@subparagraph=\count105

\c@figure=\count106

\c@table=\count107

\dropfromtop=\skip52

\extraspace=\skip53

\aboveskipchk=\skip54

\abovecaptionskip=\skip55

\belowcaptionskip=\skip56

\rotdimen=\dimen121

\tempdime=\dimen122

\temptbox=\box34



(C:\Users\chire001\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\natbib\natbib.sty

Package: natbib 2010/09/13 8.31b (PWD, AO)

\bibhang=\skip57

\bibsep=\skip58

LaTeX Info: Redefining \cite on input line 694.

\c@NAT@ctr=\count108

))

("C:\Users\chire001\Documents\Jeffrey Files\School\CompBio\Final Project\Docume

nt\document.aux")

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 5.

LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.

LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.

LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 5.

LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 5.

LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 5.

LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.

LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OT1+ptm on input line 5.

 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\psnfss\ot1ptm.fd"

File: ot1ptm.fd 2001/06/04 font definitions for OT1/ptm.

)

(C:\Users\chire001\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\context\base\supp-pdf.mkii

[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]

\scratchcounter=\count109

\scratchdimen=\dimen123

\scratchbox=\box35

\nofMPsegments=\count110

\nofMParguments=\count111

\everyMPshowfont=\toks31

\MPscratchCnt=\count112

\MPscratchDim=\dimen124

\MPnumerator=\count113

\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count114

\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks32

)

LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OT1+phv on input line 14.

 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\psnfss\ot1phv.fd"

File: ot1phv.fd 2001/06/04 scalable font definitions for OT1/phv.

)

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/phv/m/it' in size <9> not available

(Font)              Font shape `OT1/phv/m/sl' tried instead on input line 14.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/phv/bx/it' in size <9> not available

(Font)              Font shape `OT1/phv/b/it' tried instead on input line 14.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/phv/b/it' in size <9> not available

(Font)              Font shape `OT1/phv/b/sl' tried instead on input line 14.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/phv/bx/it' in size <19> not available

(Font)              Font shape `OT1/phv/b/it' tried instead on input line 14.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/phv/b/it' in size <19> not available

(Font)              Font shape `OT1/phv/b/sl' tried instead on input line 14.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/phv/m/it' in size <8> not available

(Font)              Font shape `OT1/phv/m/sl' tried instead on input line 14.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/phv/bx/n' in size <9> not available

(Font)              Font shape `OT1/phv/b/n' tried instead on input line 14.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/phv/bx/n' in size <16> not available

(Font)              Font shape `OT1/phv/b/n' tried instead on input line 14.

LaTeX Font Info:    Calculating math sizes for size <13> on input line 14.





LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmr/m/n' in size <13> not available

(Font)              size <12> substituted on input line 14.





LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmr/m/n' in size <6.5> not available

(Font)              size <6> substituted on input line 14.





LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OML/cmm/m/it' in size <13> not available

(Font)              size <12> substituted on input line 14.





LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OML/cmm/m/it' in size <6.5> not available

(Font)              size <6> substituted on input line 14.





LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OMS/cmsy/m/n' in size <13> not available

(Font)              size <12> substituted on input line 14.





LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OMS/cmsy/m/n' in size <6.5> not available

(Font)              size <6> substituted on input line 14.



LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+msa on input line 14.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\umsa.fd"

File: umsa.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A

)

LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+msb on input line 14.



("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\umsb.fd"

File: umsb.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B

)

LaTeX Font Info:    Calculating math sizes for size <9.09996> on input line 14.







LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmr/m/n' in size <4.54997> not available

(Font)              size <5> substituted on input line 14.





LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OML/cmm/m/it' in size <4.54997> not available

(Font)              size <5> substituted on input line 14.





LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OMS/cmsy/m/n' in size <4.54997> not available

(Font)              size <5> substituted on input line 14.





LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmr/m/n' in size <7.5> not available

(Font)              size <7> substituted on input line 14.





LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OML/cmm/m/it' in size <7.5> not available

(Font)              size <7> substituted on input line 14.





LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OMS/cmsy/m/n' in size <7.5> not available

(Font)              size <7> substituted on input line 14.



! Undefined control sequence.

<argument> ...2}\selectfont \raggedright \@editor 

                                                  \par } \@@par 

l.14 \maketitle



The control sequence at the end of the top line

of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have

misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct

spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,

and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.





Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) detected at line 14

[]

 []



LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/phv/bx/n' in size <8> not available

(Font)              Font shape `OT1/phv/b/n' tried instead on input line 20.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/phv/bx/n' in size <10> not available

(Font)              Font shape `OT1/phv/b/n' tried instead on input line 25.

- LAST -

Extra skip:28.55157pt

Left:87.0pt/1.77998pt

Right:58.44843pt/3.00003pt

Output:87.0pt

LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OMS+phv on input line 29.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\psnfss\omsphv.fd"

File: omsphv.fd 

)

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OMS/phv/m/n' in size <7> not available

(Font)              Font shape `OMS/cmsy/m/n' tried instead on input line 29.

 [1



{C:/Users/chire001/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}





]

("C:\Users\chire001\Documents\Jeffrey Files\School\CompBio\Final Project\Docume

nt\document.aux")



LaTeX Font Warning: Size substitutions with differences

(Font)              up to 1.0pt have occurred.



 ) 

Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:

 3376 strings out of 493921

 42650 string characters out of 3147273

 105221 words of memory out of 3000000

 6603 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000

 36737 words of font info for 84 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000

 845 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191

 37i,11n,28p,856b,294s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s

{C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/enc/dvips/fontname/8r.enc}<C:/Program File

s/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr7.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2

.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy6.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/

type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy7.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/pub

lic/amsfonts/cm/cmsy9.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/urw/helvetic

/uhvb8a.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/urw/helvetic/uhvbo8a.pfb><

C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/urw/helvetic/uhvr8a.pfb><C:/Program Fil

es/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/urw/helvetic/uhvro8a.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9

/fonts/type1/urw/times/utmr8a.pfb>

Output written on document.pdf (1 page, 75748 bytes).

PDF statistics:

 43 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)

 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)

 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

The bioinfo document class can be downloaded from [http://www.oxfordjournals.org](http://www.oxfordjournals.org/our_journals/bioinformatics/for_authors/submission_online.html).

Does anyone have any idea of what is going wrong? System is Texmaker (compiler is Miktex) on 64-bit Windows 7. Code also refuses to compile on ShareLaTeX.

Thanks!

Comment: I can't add the whole .sty file due to space limitations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `bioinfo` class requires to use `\editor`; otherwise, an error message is triggered:

```
\documentclass{bioinfo}
\copyrightyear{2014}
\pubyear{2014}

\begin{document}
\firstpage{1}

\title[QTL Analysis]{Evaluation of a QTL Dataset}
\author[Robert R. Gotwals]{Robert R. Gotwals\,\footnote{to whom correspondence should be addressed}}
\address{$^{1}$Department of XXXXXXX, Address XXXX etc.}

\history{Received on XXXXX; revised on XXXXX; accepted on XXXXX}
\editor{The Editor}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}

Here's the abstract. 

\section{Keywords:} first, second, third, fourth

\section{Contact:} \href{cowbell@ncssm.edu}{gotwals@ncssm.edu}
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore. 


\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't want to provide information for the editor, you still need to use `\editor` but with an empty argumeny:

```
\editor{}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I am a relative newbie. You may have saved my grade. No lie.

Comment: @Qu0rk You're welcome. I updated my answer with an alternative in case you don't want to provide editor information.